# Ternary operator not working in REST config params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I have this method:

```
getFolderDocuments: function(selectedFolder) {
            if (!angular.isDefined(selectedFolder.selectedTag)) {
                selectedFolder.selectedTag = {};
            }
            if (!angular.isDefined(selectedFolder.docPage)) {
                selectedFolder.docPage = 1;
            }
            if (!angular.isDefined(selectedFolder.pageLimit)) {
                selectedFolder.pageLimit = 10;
            }
            var sort = "desc";
            if (selectedFolder.sortDesc == false) {
                sort = "asc";
            }

            var config = {
                'params': {
                    filters: {
                        authorised: (angular.isDefined(selectedFolder.authorised) && selectedFolder.authorised ? true : false),
                        tag: (angular.isDefined(selectedFolder.selectedTag.id) ? selectedFolder.selectedTag.id : 0),
                        title: (angular.isDefined(selectedFolder.titleFilter) ? selectedFolder.titleFilter : ""),
                        start: ((angular.isDefined(selectedFolder.startFilter) && selectedFolder.startFilter != null) ? selectedFolder.startFilter.getTime() : 0),
                        end: ((angular.isDefined(selectedFolder.endFilter) && selectedFolder.endFilter != null) ? selectedFolder.endFilter.getTime() : 0)},
                    sort: sort,
                    page: selectedFolder.docPage,
                    limit: selectedFolder.pageLimit}
            };
            return $http.get(RESTServer.REST_URL+'/rest/mobile/folder/' + selectedFolder.id + "/document", config);
        }
```

This is supposed to filter a list of documents given specific parameters, like tags, title, creation date, etc...

The problem is that I have been checking the values in the console and the ternary operator (in the tag parameter, for example) always returns the false value, even though the element in the evaluation expression is defined.

How can I solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take your tag parameter for example

```
(angular.isDefined(selectedFolder.selectedTag.id) ? selectedFolder.selectedTag.id : 0),
```

It is **correctly** returning **false** because selectedFolder.selectedTag.id is not defined.

```
selectedFolder.selectedTag = {}
```

There is no id in there, unless you are passing in a different object in the function parameter, which we have no way of knowing. Please clean up your question.

Comment: But it is defined in the method argument. That condition happens only when the selectedTag property of the argument is not defined. If I check in the console output the selectedTag.id returns a value and the config.params.filter.tag returns 0

Comment: What are you passing into your method? You could be passing an empty object {} for all I know, please clean up your question.

Comment: I am passing into the method a value defined in the $scope.selectedFolder property. It is never undefined. This is an example of the output:
console.log(selectedFolder.selectedTag.id) = 0,1,2,3.... etc
console.log(config.params.filters.tag) = 0 always